# GeoDjango Admin: Adding PointField latitude and longitude to other fields

Tags: geodjango, django

I've been redesigning my application to allow users to set markers more easily. One thing I need to include for backwards compatibility purposes is that the new model must have a latitude and longitude field in the database.

Is it possible to modify the GeoDjango admin so that the latitude/longitude fields automatically populate after I select a point on the map?

Here's a screenshot of how my admin is currently:
[image: admin image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up solving this by overriding the admin model in admin.py, and setting the  latitude/longitude fields as read-only like this:

```
class MarkerAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    default_lon = -93
    default_lat = 27
    default_zoom = 15
    readonly_fields = ('Latitude','Longitude')
admin.site.register(Marker, MarkerAdmin)
```

I then modified the relevant model in my models.py to override the save function so that it assigned the longitude and latitude fields from the PointField.

```
class Marker(models.Model):
    MarkerID= models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    Name= models.CharField(max_length=40)
    mpoint = models.PointField()
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    Latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6)
    Longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.Latitude  = self.mpoint.y
        self.Longitude = self.mpoint.x   
        super(Marker, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```